# How to use issue trackers for internal systems?

Tags: issue-tracking

I'm working for a company where I develop systems purely for internal use. There are only a few developers but we use redmine for issue tracking & feature requests. However, the only people with access to the issue tracker are team leaders, everyone else is meant to feed their suggestions through their team leader.

The idea is that this will reduce developer workload and give management more control over the features being developed. The reality is that we get emails sent directly to us from people experiencing small bugs, or feature requests.

Is this a sane way to manage user feedback or a known bad practice? I've not seen any articles which discuss managing internal issue tracking, so thought I'd ask you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow your users to access Redmine and create them a special role where they can only create new issues with a new status then the project managers or the team leaders can priorize the issues and assign them to the right people.
It will imply that your users have to be trained to use the tool to create efficient reports and search before creating a new one. But if it's an internal project it will be "easier" because you can train everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds sane to me. If you have end-users giving you feedback then that's a good thing. I've no experience with redmine but if there's a learning-curve associated with it then end-users may be reluctant to bother giving feedback at all. Also, you may end up with defect targets such as 'it has to triaged with X days, and fixed by Y days'. By having such an informal feedback process you avoid this. Also, your team could take a somewhat Agile approach and write bugs/feature requests onto scorecards and stick them on a wall so everybody can see them, including managers - who get to see how end-users are really using your product, and choose to fix/implement them as your team sees fit, with the priority that you choose yourselves.

Of course, your source control system will have the history of all fixes and new features!